# IIS web deploy how to remove/ unassign user from web deploy

Tags: iis-7, deployment

As in [guide link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/install/installing-publishing-technologies/installing-and-configuring-web-deploy) from microsoft, I can setup web deployment for my website and assign user X so X can publish code to site.

Now I want to remove user X so that X cann't publish to site. How to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Just disable the nonadmin user you created inside computer management -> users & groups -> users.

Depending on your use case It might be enough to just change the users password on the server if you have some deployment pipeline that has the password stored.

Another option is local policy - deny login rights for the user.

Any of the above should prevent webdeploy deploying and can be easily undone later to re-enable deployments

Based on your comment...

Ok, try creating a deny rule on the webroot directory to block access to the single site? Just remove the deny permission before a deployment and add it afterwards. This is not very elegant but should allow for your desired behaviour.

Comment: Thank you, your solution disable all right from that user by delete or disable that user. I only want to disable user from deploying website Y, but he can deploy to others website (Z, T, ...). The problem is web deploy in IIS only allow to add user, not remove. I don't want to delete a website then create, add deploy user  again only to remove one user from web deploy...

Answer (score 0):

You can remove users from the `Configure Web Deploy Publishing` screen by denying them access through the IIS feature: `IIS Manager Permissions`

To remove the user globally:

1. Open IIS
2. Click the server name
3. Select `IIS Manager Permissions` from the `Management` section of the feature list (the grid of icons in the centre of the IIS panel),
4. From here you should be able to see the user
5. Right-click the user and select `Deny User` then click `Yes` when asked to confirm

The user should now be gone from the `Configure Web Deploy Publishing` screen

The same steps *should* be applicable for single sites, but I have never tested this

Comment: Sorry about the really slow reply, I just found this question myself through Google and figured answering it would help out anyone who sees this in the future